# How can i use windows api for keyboard?

Tags: c#, winapi, kinect

Im trying to make my keyboard work with kinect sdk.How can i do it? what is the right windows Api for it? for example when i said something my proggram sumulates keyboard function for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you'll need is `SendKeys`.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

So something like this will simulate pressing the "Enter" key on demand:

```
SendKeys::Send("{ENTER}");
```